# JSON.net Generating a lot of extra Square brackets

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to generate the following json with JSON.Net but it is  adding alot of extra square brackets with what should I do
Needed Json

```
 {
    "addUser": {
      "idCard": "xxx",
      "firstName": "xxx",
      "surname": "Muscat",
      "isActive": true,
      "titleDesc": "xx",
      "genderDesc": "Female",
      "emailAddress":"",
      "mobileNumber":"",
      "telephoneNumber":"",
      "dob":""
    }
  }
```

C# code

```
var obj = new JObject();
obj.Add(
    new JProperty("addUser",
        new JArray(
            new JObject(
                new JProperty("idCard", doct.First().idCard.PadLeft(8, '0')),
                new JProperty ("firstName", det.First().PersonName),
                new JProperty("surname", det.First().PersonSurname),
                new JProperty("isActive", true),
                new JProperty("titleDesc", ""),
                new JProperty("genderDesc", det.First().PersonGenderDesc),
                new JProperty("emailAddress", ""),
                new JProperty("mobileNumber", ""),
                new JProperty("telephoneNumber", ""),
                new JProperty("dob", det.First().PersonBirthDate)
                ))));
```

Comment: Could you show the generated JSON, too, please?

Comment: Why do you create a your object like that? Create a c# class that maps to your JSON. JSON.Net you take care of serializing/deserializing for you.

Comment: `new JArray(` <-- well, that's where your square brackets come from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you already have a json string and want it to map it to a C# class construct you can use the intigrated Visual Studio function *Paste Json as Classes*.

1. Copy some JSON
2. Select Edit –> Paste Special –> Paste JSON As Classes

[image]

If you do so Visual Studio will make for you this two classes:

```
public class Rootobject
{
   public Adduser addUser { get; set; }
}

public class Adduser
{
   public string idCard { get; set; }
   public string firstName { get; set; }
   public string surname { get; set; }
   public bool isActive { get; set; }
   public string titleDesc { get; set; }
   public string genderDesc { get; set; }
   public string emailAddress { get; set; }
   public string mobileNumber { get; set; }
   public string telephoneNumber { get; set; }
   public string dob { get; set; }
}
```

With this Visual Studio tool you get a first idea how to map your json string to C# classes.

Now if you have an object of your class, you can simply convert it with `JsonConvert`

```
var myObject = new Rootobject() { addUser = new Adduser() { idCard = 1, ...} };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);
```

To deserialize you simply call:

```
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
```

Comment: @StevenRands It was added in VS2013 Update 2, AFAIK.